# Evaluating the Determinant of all nxn Boolean Matrices

Tags: matrix

I need help (the help being essential as I have no idea where to start) in creating a program that will not only determine all possible nxn Boolean matrices but also evaluates their determinants and then stores the answers in a readable format. The real confusion for me is how to make Mathematica change the entries and not repeat itself. If anyone could help it would much appreciated!!

Comment: What have you tried? What do you specifically mean by `n x n` Boolean matrix here?

Comment: Define "readable format".

Answer (score 3):

I take Boolean matrix to refer to a [logical matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_matrix) here, i.e. a matrix whose entries are either $0$ or $1$. You can use `Tuples` to generate such matrices directly:

```
Clear[boolmat]
boolmat[n_Integer /; n > 0] := Tuples[{0, 1}, {n, n}]

MatrixForm /@ boolmat[2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can then calculate the determinant of each one by mapping `Det` over the list:

```
Det /@ boolmat[2]
(* Out: {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, -1, 0} *)
```